# example for$(a_n+b_n)$ diverges to $\infty$ or $-\infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given $a_n\rightarrow \infty$, $b_n\rightarrow -\infty$

I need an example for  $(a_n+b_n)$ disverges from $\infty$ to $-\infty$.

I tried to think of an example but i have a problem to find the sum.

for example i took $a_n=2,4,6,8,...$ and $b_n=-1,-3,-5,...$.

Then $a_n+b_n$ oscillates infinitely but not to $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Thanks.

Comment: Add hypothesis about $a_n$ and $b_n$ to title may help.

Comment: i think the question means to find one example such that the sum will tends from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two examples.

> - Take $a_n:=n^2$, $b_n:=-n$, then $a_n+b_n = n \times (n-1)\to +\infty$.
> - Take $a_n:=\sqrt{n}$, $b_n:=-n$, then $a_n+b_n = \sqrt{n} \times (1-\sqrt{n})\to -\infty$.

Comment: i think the question means to find one example such that the sum will tends from $-\infty$ to $\infty$